# Identical CSS behaves differently when applied to either body or a div

Tags: css

### [Using a DIV as container](http://codepen.io/erethnor/pen/HsBol)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="half-hidden"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;

  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.half-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: -50px;
  width: 100px;

  border: 1px solid teal;
}
```

[image: Rendered page with a container]

### [Using body as container](http://codepen.io/erethnor/pen/aIcfF)

```
<div class="half-hidden"></div>
```

CSS

Replace the above `.container` with `body`

[image: Rendered page using body as container]

**Why?**

Comment: I think it's quite obvious. The container puts a guard around your internal div so it conforms to some rules that it obeys already. These rules are the dimensions specifically.

Comment: I would guess that it is because a body doesn't have an overflow - it can never overflow - so the overflow won't be hidden.

Comment: @AndyG that would be my guess as well, but the overflow is not shown as overridden by the UA stylesheet, and I couldn't find any special `body` rule on w3c specs.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question but this article seems somewhat relevant - http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html

Comment: hmmm, strange.  in the codepen, even if you style `<html>` with `overflow:hidden` instead of `<body>`, it still doesn't hide the overflow.  You need to style `overflow:hidden` on both the body and html elements and then it hides the overflow

Comment: @AndyG that could be true. Can you give any evidence why it does not have overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [W3 Offical Doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow) says, and @Andy G too,  doesn't have an overflow. In that case, overflow will be applied by UAs to the first child:

> UAs must apply the 'overflow' property set on the root element to the
>   viewport. When the root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML
>   "html" element, and that element has an HTML "BODY" element or an
>   XHTML "body" element as a child, user agents must instead apply the
>   'overflow' property from the first such child element to the viewport,
>   if the value on the root element is 'visible'. The 'visible' value
>   when used for the viewport must be interpreted as 'auto'. The element
>   from which the value is propagated must have a used value for
>   'overflow' of 'visible'.

Comment: Not the easiest piece of documentation to read. If I understood it correctly, it means "IF `html { overflow: visible }` THEN `html { overflow: stealBodyOverflowValue }`", which also explains @ChrisM finding.

Answer (score 0):

hi friends add this css in your code

```
.container {
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  right:-100px;
}

.half-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid teal;
  float:left;
  margin-left:-50px
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="half-hidden"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not looking for a "fix", just the reason